# SSRS: Patterns for conditional dataset definitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2012

I am developing SSRS reports that require a user selection (via a parameter) to retrieve either *live* data or *historical* data.

The sources for live and historical data are separate objects in a SQL Server database (views for live data; table-valued functions accepting a date parameter for historical data), but their schemas - the columns they return - are the same, so other than the dataset definition, the rest of the report doesn't need to know what its source is.

The dataset query draws from several database objects, and it contains joins and case statements in the select.

There are several approaches I can take to surfacing data from different sources based on the parameter selection I've described (some of which I've tested), listed below.

The main goal is to ensure that performance for retrieving the *live* data (primary use case) is not unduly affected by the presence of logic and harnessing to support the *history* use case. In addition, ease maintainability of the solution (including database objects and rdl) is a secondary, but important, factor.

1. Use an expression in the dataset query text, to conditionally return full SQL query text with the correct sources included using string concatenation. **Pros**: can resolve to a straight query that isn't polluted by the 'other' use case for any given execution. All logic for the report is housed in the report. **Cons**: awful to work with, and has limitations for lengthy SQL.
2. Use a function in the report's code module to do the same as 1. **Pros**: as per 1., but marginally better design-time experience. **Cons**: as per 1., but also adds another layer of abstraction that reduces ease of maintenance.
3. Implement multi-step TVFs on the database, that process the parameter and retrieve the correct data using logic in T-SQL. **Pros**: flexibility of t-SQL functionality, no string building/substitution involved. Can select * from its results and apply further report parameters in the report's dataset query. **Cons**: big performance hit when compared to in-line queries. Moves some logic outside the rdl.
4. Implement stored procedures to do the same as 3. **Pros**: as per 3, but without ease of select *. **Cons**: as per 3.
5. Implement in-line TVFs that union together live and history data, but using a dummy input parameter that adds something that resolves to 1=0 in the where clause of the source that isn't relevant. **Pros**: clinging on to the in-line query approach, other pros as per 3. **Cons**: feels like a hack, adds performance hit just for a query component that is known to return 0 rows. Adds complexity to the query.

I am leaning towards options 3 or 4 at this point, but eager to hear **what would be a preferred approach** (even if not listed here) and why?

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference between live and historical? Is "live" data, data that changes and historical does not?

Is it not possible to replicate or push live/historical data into a Data Warehouse built specifically for reporting?

Comment: "Live" data is queried directly from the source application database. There is a requirement for it to be live, no lag, therefore no pushing it to an ODS/DW. Historical data is pushed to a DW overnight.